# Lambda Expression to get the cells vertically for a section containing rows

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have to iterate through each section and create the cells for rows to ultimately create a table. Here each Section has rows `0....n`, and Rows have cells say `0...n`

For example as illustrated below:

```
Row 0->   Cell0 | Cell1| Cell2 | Cell3 | Cell4 | Cell5         
Row 1->   Cell0 | Cell1| Cell2 | Cell3 | Cell4 | Cell5      
Row 2->   Cell0 | Cell1| Cell2 | Cell3 | Cell4 | Cell5     
..
```

I want to create a lambda expression (say):

```
var allColumns = ...........
```

To get all Cell0's then all Cell1's, all Cell2's etc... so that I can iterate in loop and create a table for each. The requirement does not want me to go row by row but it wants me to go column by column (cell as illustrated above in the diagram, I create the the cell0's first then cell1's then cell 2's etc, like in the loop below.

```
foreach(Cell c in allColumns){
    //I want to iterate in this loop and create my cells and rows.    
}
```

Can you help give me the lambda expression for this.

I tried doing this

```
var allColumns = Sections.Rows.SelectMany(a=>a.Cells).GroupBy(What should come here).
```

Can you improve or suggest a better Lambda expression keeping the above foreach loop and           illustration above in mind. thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of collection is it and what datatype does it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this demo which I had put together and see if it works for you (it should be put in a Windows console application):

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { 
               new DataColumn("col1"), 
               new DataColumn("col2"), 
               new DataColumn("col3") });

        dt.Rows.Add("cell0", "cell1", "cell2");
        dt.Rows.Add("cell0", "cell1", "cell2");
        dt.Rows.Add("cell0", "cell1", "cell2");
        dt.Rows.Add("cell0", "cell1", "cell2");

        // writes out the original data
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var column in row.ItemArray)
                Console.Write("{0} ", column);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        // reverses columns and rows
        var result = dt.Columns
                       .Cast<DataColumn>()
                       .Select(column => 
                          dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(row => 
                               row.ItemArray[column.Ordinal].ToString()));

        // writes out the reversed columns and rows
        foreach (var row in result)
        {
            foreach(var column in row)
                Console.Write("{0} ",column);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net) Demo Program

I took Ivan Gs Code and created a Linqpad Program

[image: Get Columns of DataTable]

```
void Main(){        
    // get and write out the original data
    var dt = GetDataTable();
    dt.Dump();
    // get columns
    var result = GetColumnsFromDataTable(dt);
    result.ElementAt(0).Dump();
    result.ElementAt(1).Dump();
    result.ElementAt(2).Dump(); 
}
   
private IEnumerable<EnumerableRowCollection<String>> GetColumnsFromDataTable(DataTable dt){

    // Lambda Expression to get the cells 
    // vertically for a section containing rows     
    var result = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
               .Select(column =>  dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row => row.ItemArray[column.Ordinal].ToString()));   
    return result;
}

private DataTable GetDataTable(){
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { 
        new DataColumn("col1 id"), 
        new DataColumn("col2 name"), 
        new DataColumn("col3 job") 
    });
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "John", "Barista");
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "Mike", "Handyman");
    dt.Rows.Add("3", "Jane", "Teacher");
    dt.Rows.Add("4", "Quentin", "Producer");
    return dt;
}
```